# Mark radio using unserialize inside foreach

Tags: php

I would like to know how the correct way is to get the checkbox checked.

Currently looping inside loop ...

In the first `foreach` it lists all the options to be marked, as in the image below:

[image]

In the second `foreach` it would be to mark the option that is coming from the DB. It checks with this code `<?php  if($checkIni[$key] == "tem"){echo "checked ";}; ?>`. What changes is the value that is **TEM, NAO, AVA**.

```
<?php
    $checklistIni = "a:16:{i:0;s:3:"nao";i:1;s:3:"ava";i:2;s:3:"tem";i:3;s:3:"tem";i:4;s:3:"tem";i:5;s:3:"tem";i:6;s:3:"tem";i:7;s:3:"tem";i:8;s:3:"tem";i:9;s:3:"tem";i:10;s:3:"tem";i:11;s:3:"tem";i:12;s:3:"tem";i:13;s:3:"tem";i:14;s:3:"tem";i:15;s:3:"tem";}";

    $checkIni = unserialize($checklistIni );

    foreach($rsChecklist as $checklist) {
        foreach($checkIni as $key => $val){

?>


  <tr>
    <td class="texto-branco">
      <?php echo $checklist['nome'] ?>
    </td>
    <td><label><input value="tem" name="checklistFim<?php echo $checklist['ID_Checklist'] ?>" class="checklistFim" type="radio" <?php  if($checkIni[$key] == "tem"){echo "checked ";}; ?> /><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label><input value="nao" name="checklistFim<?php echo $checklist['ID_Checklist'] ?>" class="checklistFim" type="radio" <?php  if($checkIni[$key] == "nao"){echo "checked ";}; ?> /><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label><input value="ava" name="checklistFim<?php echo $checklist['ID_Checklist'] ?>" class="checklistFim" type="radio" <?php  if($checkIni[$key] == "ava"){echo "checked ";}; ?> /><span></span></label></td>
  </tr>


  <?php
        };
    };
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little messed up, by the way hope I can help you with this:

```
$checklistIni = 'a:16:{i:0;s:3:"nao";i:1;s:3:"ava";i:2;s:3:"tem";i:3;s:3:"tem";i:4;s:3:"tem";i:5;s:3:"tem";i:6;s:3:"tem";i:7;s:3:"tem";i:8;s:3:"tem";i:9;s:3:"tem";i:10;s:3:"tem";i:11;s:3:"tem";i:12;s:3:"tem";i:13;s:3:"tem";i:14;s:3:"tem";i:15;s:3:"tem";}';

$checkIni = unserialize($checklistIni);
$rsChecklist = array(
array(
    'nome' => 'A',
)
);

foreach ($rsChecklist as $k => $checklist) {
foreach ($checkIni as $key => $val) {

    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="texto-branco">
                <?php echo $checklist['nome'] ?>
            </td>
            <td><label><input value="tem" name="checklistFim<?php echo $key ?>" class="checklistFim"
                              type="radio" <?php if ($val == "tem") {
                        echo "checked='checked' ";
                    }; ?> /><span></span></label></td>
            <td><label><input value="nao" name="checklistFim<?php echo $key ?>" class="checklistFim"
                              type="radio" <?php if ($val == "nao") {
                        echo "checked='checked' ";
                    }; ?> /><span></span></label></td>
            <td><label><input value="ava" name="checklistFim<?php echo $key ?>" class="checklistFim"
                              type="radio" <?php if ($val == "ava") {
                        echo "checked='checked' ";
                    }; ?> /><span></span></label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <?php
}
}
```

Essentially you have to change those lines `<input value="tem" name="checklistFim<?php echo $checklist['ID_Checklist'] ?>" class="checklistFim" type="radio" <?php  if($checkIni[$key] == "tem"){echo "checked ";}; ?> />`
The `name` attribute must be the same for each of three radio in lane and different with others lanes.